# Add existing source code folders into Local Git Repository

Tags: git, git-add

Let's say I have two existing folders that I want to put under `Git` source control. One is called `CurrentProduction` and the other `CurrentDevelopment`. Would the following steps be correct?

1. Create a new folder called `MyProject`

   `git init`

   Move the `CurrentProduction` contents to `MyProject`

   `git add .`

   `git commit -m 'initial master commit'`

   `git checkout -b develop`

   Delete all files in `MyProject` (except for the .git folder of course)

   Move the `CurrentDevelopment` contents to `MyProject`

   `git add -A`

   `git commit -m 'initial develop commit'`

Or is there a "different" way?

Comment: Sounds correct yes. Make sure there's no junk in these directories. Having said that why not just try?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Doing it the way you describe will not do any harm.
- You can move the `.git` directory into the tree you want to commit instead of moving the tree to the repository.
- You can use the `--work-tree` option or `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable to act as if you did that:

  ```
  git add --work-tree=CurrentProduction -A; git commit ...
  ```

  Note that it is not necessary to specify it for commands after `add` since `add` copies content into the index, `commit` uses the index, and the index is in `.git`.

As a separate issue, note that your procedure will make the `develop` initial commit a child of the `master` initial commit. That is probably the right thing for this case; I just want to make sure you're aware it's not symmetric.

Comment: I tried using `git add --work-tree` but it does not work. I can't find any info about the `--work-tree` option (especially for `git add`). I'm using git version 1.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good way.

The only possible issue if you look at the history of the develop branch with `git log` you will have the current production project state as last commit (the one with 'initial master commit'). Which semantically not fully correct.

If that bothers you can **make first an initial empty commit** which servers as a common base for the two branches:

```
git init .
git commit --allow-empty -m "initial commit"
# add CurrentProduction content
git add .
git commit -m "initial master commit"

# checkout at the empty commit
git checkout -b develop HEAD^

# no need to delete any files!
# working tree is empty
# add CurrentDevelopment  content
git add .
git commit -m "initial develop commit"
```